# Jaspersoft ireport designer 4.5.1 /4.6.0 & hive

Tags: jasper-reports

I am trying to design a report using hive connection.
I created hive connection and tested it is working ok.

Is there anything i am doing wrong. I am new to iReport.

jdbc:hive://192.168.254.132:10000/default

I am using report designer, I typed in my HiveQL it gives REPORT_CONNECTION parameter not specified.

I have specified the hive connection.

i tried simple query, select * from iptable.

message:
    net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Parameter "REPORT_CONNECTION" does not exist.
Level:
    SEVERE
Stack Trace:
Parameter "REPORT_CONNECTION" does not exist.
    com.jaspersoft.hadoop.hive.HiveFieldsProvider.getFields(HiveFieldsProvider.java:88)
    com.jaspersoft.ireport.hadoop.hive.designer.HiveFieldsProvider.getFields(HiveFieldsProvider.java:32)
    com.jaspersoft.ireport.hadoop.hive.connection.HiveConnection.readFields(HiveConnection.java:154)
    com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.wizards.ConnectionSelectionWizardPanel.validate(ConnectionSelectionWizardPanel.java:146)
    org.openide.WizardDescriptor$7.run(WizardDescriptor.java:1357)
    org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:572)
    org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:997)

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is a little embarrassing. The wizard worked fine in iReport 4.5.0. But it broke in 4.5.1, and somehow no one noticed it. Reports still work fine, so the bug evaded tests. It seems to affect only the Fields Provider. So it shows up in the wizard but not when running the report.

I uploaded a fixed version of the plugin seconds ago. You'll need to uninstall the existing Hadoop Hive plugin, then restart iReport, then install the updated plugin. Then all should be well.

Here's the [general project link](http://jasperforge.org/projects/bigdatareportingfornosqlandhadoop). Here's the [new file](http://jasperforge.org/plugins/esp_frs/file.php?id=117&group_id=428&relid=118) linked directly. This should all be obsolete when the next version of iReport ships with the fixed Hive plugin.