# iReport designer 4.5.1 /4.6.0 cannot interact with Hive

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, hive

I have followed the instructions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11671933/jaspersoft-ireport-designer-4-5-1-4-6-0-hive) and installed the updated plugin. The error has become:

```
Query error

Message: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: 
Error executing SQL statement for : null Level: SEVERE Stack Trace: 
Error executing SQL statement for : null com.jaspersoft.hadoop.hive.HiveFieldsProvider.getFields(HiveFieldsProvider.java:113)
com.jaspersoft.ireport.hadoop.hive.designer.HiveFieldsProvider.getFields(HiveFieldsProvider.java:32)
com.jaspersoft.ireport.hadoop.hive.connection.HiveConnection.readFields(HiveConnection.java:154)
com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.wizards.ConnectionSelectionWizardPanel.validate(ConnectionSelectionWizardPanel.java:146)
org.openide.WizardDescriptor$7.run(WizardDescriptor.java:1357)
org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:572)
org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:997)
```

After downgrading to 4.5.0 the error has become (the connection is verified and I am able to query the table from hive):

```
Query error

Message: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Query returned non-zero code: 10, cause: 
FAILED: Error in semantic analysis: Line 1:14 Table not found 'panstats' Level: 
SEVERE Stack Trace: Query returned non-zero code: 10, cause: 
FAILED: Error in semantic analysis: Line 1:14 Table not found 'panstats'
com.jaspersoft.hadoop.hive.HiveFieldsProvider.getFields(HiveFieldsProvider.java:260)
com.jaspersoft.ireport.hadoop.hive.designer.HiveFieldsProvider.getFields(HiveFieldsProvider.java:32)
com.jaspersoft.ireport.hadoop.hive.connection.HiveConnection.readFields(HiveConnection.java:146)
com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.wizards.ConnectionSelectionWizardPanel.validate(ConnectionSelectionWizardPanel.java:146)
org.openide.WizardDescriptor$7.run(WizardDescriptor.java:1357)
org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:572)
org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:997)
```

I am using *Hive 0.8.1* on *OS X Lion 10.7.4.*

Answer (score 0):

Is your query as simple as `select * from panstats`? I suspect that the query is not the problem, but you'll want to confirm that first.

You could try querying that table from a tool like SQuirreL SQL. If that tool also cannot get the data, then it's probably a Hive issue. If it can... then it's probably an issue with iReport or the Hive plugin.

It sounds like Hive is not configured to share metadata. It uses the annoying default configuration with Derby, so outside connections don't get access to your panstats table. I came across [this article](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/02/big-data-analytics-with-hive-and.html) about configuring Hive earlier this year. It documents using MySQL instead of derby. If that's indeed the problem, then it's just a Hive configuration issue. Following that article would solve things both for SQuirreL and for iReport.